# How to get index of an array with MouseListener?

Tags: java, arrays, mouselistener

I'm creating a calendar with each date represented by a JTextArea. I created an array of JTextAreas for all the dates on the calendar of a given month.

This is CalenderFrame class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;



public class CalendarFrame extends JFrame{

private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 700;
private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 700;

private static final int NUM_OF_CELLS = 35;
private static final int DIM_OF_CELLS = 3;

private JLabel month;
private JPanel panel;
private CellBox[] allCells;
String text = "";




public CalendarFrame(){

    month = new JLabel("October");
    add(month, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    class CellListener implements MouseListener{


        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Set text for date: ");
            System.out.println(text);
            allCells[].get.setText(text);

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }



    }
    CellListener listener = new CellListener();

    createCellsPanel();
    for(int k= 0; k < NUM_OF_CELLS; k++){

        allCells[k].getCell().addMouseListener(listener);

    }
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);

}

public CellBox[] createAllCells(int numOfCells){

    CellBox[] cells = new CellBox[numOfCells];

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_CELLS; i++){
        cells[i].createCell(new JTextArea(DIM_OF_CELLS, DIM_OF_CELLS));
        Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK);
        cells[i].getCell().setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(border, BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10)));
        cells[i].getCell().setEditable(false);

        cells[i].setCellNum(i);

    }
    return cells;


}

public void createCellsPanel(){

    allCells = createAllCells(NUM_OF_CELLS);
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,7));
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_CELLS; i++){
        panel.add(allCells[i]);
    }

    add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


}

public void popOutEvent(){

}

}
```

The main class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CalendarFrameViewer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new CalendarFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

and the CellBox class

```
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class CellBox {

private int cellNum;
private int date;
private JTextArea cell;

public void setCellNum(int num){
    cellNum = num;
}

public void setDate(int date){
    this.date = date;
}

public void createCell(JTextArea cell){
    this.cell = cell;
}

public int getCellNum(){
    return cellNum;
}

public int getDate(){
    return date;
}

public JTextArea getCell(){
    return cell;
}
}
```

I want to be able to click on a cell and set the text within the cell. How would I retrieve a cell number or index number?

Comment: Can you write up a [MCVE] of this? You just have a snippet of code and then a bunch of verbiage about mouse listeners without much other context. Nobody can actually try your code and easily see what you're asking or talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is (I think) how can I retrieve the cell number for the component that has been clicked on? If so, the simplest solution is to have a mouse listener that is specific to each text area.

For example, you could have the following method:

```
private JTextArea makeCell(final int id) {
    JTextArea cell = new JTextArea(DIM_OF_CELLS, DIM_OF_CELLS));
    cell.setBorder(...);
    cell.setEditable(false);
    cell.addMouseListener(new MouseAdaptor() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev) {
            String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Set text for date: ");
            allCells[id].get.setText(text);      
        }
    });
    return cell;
}
```

However I think you're underlying problem is that you have only half encapsulated the `CellBox` class. Rather than having a `getCell` method to give access to the `JTextArea` you would be better off creating the component inside that class as well as providing the mouse listener. Then you wouldn't need to access the cell with the index at all. In fact I doubt you'd need to store the index at all.

```
public class CellBox {
    private final JTextArea cell;

    public CellBox() {
        cell = new JTextArea(DIM_OF_CELLS, DIM_OF_CELLS));
        cell.setBorder(...);
        cell.setEditable(false);
        cell.addMouseListener(new MouseAdaptor() {
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent ev) {
                String text = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Set text for date: ");
                cell.setText(text);      
            }
        });
    }
}
```